# VB.NET enter text on textbox and press send webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, forms, timer, getattribute

I'm calling a ton of webpages from a listbox and when each page loads, I want to send a message to the user before the timer goes to the next page. The page contains a form that has a textbox and a button that sends the contents of the form. Below is my code and the form I'm trying to submit to.

The problem is that as soon as the timer goes to the next web page, it adds the information to the textbox and clicks the button, but it does it at the last minute just as it's loading the next page, and there isn't enough time to submit the form. I've tried increasing the time that the timer has but this hasn't worked. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If counter > ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.myserver.com/listofusers.aspx")
        counter = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button1.Text = "Message the unmessaged"
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    Else


        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button1.Text = "Working... "
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox2.Items(counter))
        Dim theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
        For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
            Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString
            If controlName = "profile" Then
                curElement.SetAttribute("value", "Your password is due to expire in 10 days, please change it as soon as possible")
            End If
        Next


        Dim theElementCollection2 = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection2
            If curElement.GetAttribute("className").Equals("button norm-green") Then
                curElement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
    End If
    counter = counter + 1

End Sub
```

The form:

```
<form action="sendmessage.aspx" method="post" name="sendmessage">

                <div class="aligncenter">
                    <span class="headline txtBlue size16">Send a Quick Message!</span>
                    <input maxlength="40" name="subject" size="33" type="hidden" 
                        value="Important information" />
                    <textarea class="profile" name="message"></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" class="button norm-green" style="" value="Send Quick Msg" name="sendmessage" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted my issue. I placed the for each webbrowser statements within the webbrowser1.documentcompleted() control and put a if timer1.enabled = true statement around it.